# Number Representation- Floating point, decimal point, binary point and fixed point

Tags: floating-point, terminology, fixed-point, decimal-point

I don't understand these terms:

- Fixed point
- floating point
- binary point
- decimal point

I don't understand when to apply which representation and what is the difference between these terminologies.

`2` is a fixed point representation according to me because it is an integer, but I don't understand the reason behind this. And how is `2` represented in fixed point representation? Can `2` also be a floating point or binary point?

I'm asking these questions because I don't even know the meaning of these four terms. Please explain all the four terms in simple words with some examples.

Answer (score 3):

A decimal point is punctuation that marks where the integer digits of a number end and the fraction digits begin. For example, in the sentence “Pi is about 3.14”, the period is a decimal point. The 3 represents a number of ones, and the 1 represents a number of tenths.

A binary point is the same as a decimal point but is used when referring to binary numerals, such as “11.00100”. A radix point is the same thing for any radix (any base used for a positional numerical system).

Fixed point represents a number with another number and knowledge of a fixed position where the radix point is. For example, if we have integers built into the computer but want to work with dollars and cents, we might decide the radix point will be put at two digits up from the integers. So, to represent 73.25 in the computer’s integers, we would store 7325.

Integers are a special case of fixed point: The radix point is in a known, fixed position, which happens to be the normal position.

Floating point represents a number with a number and a second number that says where to put the radix point. For example, 73.25 could be represent with 7325 and -2. And 7325 and 1 would be 73250. The point is not fixed; it floats as detemined by the second number.

In computers, fixed-point is often done using binary. So the fixed-point may be set at a fixed number of binary digits. Saying the point is fixed at three binary digits to the left of the usual integer radix is equivalent to saying divide the integer by 8 (2<sup>3</sup>). [Abbreviations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)) are used to describe the formats: Q3 stands for signed fixed-point with three fraction bits. That leaves out the number of integer bits, so it would be implicit in the objects being used to store the numbers. Q12.3 means 12 integer bits and 3 fraction bits.

In floating-point, the two numbers are called the significand or fraction and the exponent (because shifting the radix point by a number of digits is equivalent to multiplying by the radix raised to the power of the number of digits shifted). Often, the sign (+ or -) is separated from the significand. The sign, exponent, and significand are often encoded as fields in one object.

Arithmetic on fixed-point numbers can be implemented using integer arithmetic with some adjustments. Arithmetic on floating-point numbers is most often done using hardware with built-in support for floating-point.